# getApplicationContext() cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use a method to generate a bitmap from Layouts and save the bitmap to a file in the internal memory. However, the getApplicationContext() is not resolved.

Here is the code for the method

```
    private void generateAndSaveBitmap(View layout) {
//Generate bitmap
        layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        layout.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap imageToSave = layout.getDrawingCache();

//Create a file and path
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File fileName = new File(directory, "sharableImage.jpg");
        if (fileName.exists())
            fileName.delete();

//Compress and save bitmap under the mentioned fileName
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
//    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Used some help from StackOverFlow codes to generate this method. Even after reading related queries on `getApplicationContext()`, I am unable to find the issue. Any help would be really appreciated

EDIT : Forgot to mention, that the method `generateAndSaveBitmap(View layout)` is defined inside a separate class

Regards

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` is a method on `Context`. Does your class extent `Context` in some direct or indirect way?

Comment: when using buildDrawingCache(); you also need to destroy it after using it

Comment: @user3802077 thanks for the point. Added to the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Delete `ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());`, as you do not need it.

Step #2: Replace `cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` with `layout.getContext().getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Also, please move this disk I/O to a background thread.

Comment: Thanks for remaining about the background thread. Forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try ,

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getActivity());
```

incase it's a  fragment.

Comment: Already came across getActivity(). But nope. It ain't a fragment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
File dir = getApplicationContext().getDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Now, from the image processing to the write of the file into the directory everything should be done off thread. Encapsulate it in an AsyncTask when possible and within it move `generateAndSaveBitmap()` method to it.